# Wordpress add custom page without adding template

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, wordpress-theming

I have a custom page called settings.php in my theme folder, I don't want to use it as page template.

How can I reserve a URL let's call it mysite.com/settings, so this url will load settings.php page for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new page called 'settings' . And add this code in your functions.php

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/settings') !== false){
               include(get_template_directory(). '/settings.php');
       }
```